# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value in case statement

Tags: sql-server, case

I cant not get my head around it. We have following simple query.

```
DECLARE @bFlag bit
SET @bFlag = 0
SELECT  something = CASE
                WHEN @bFlag = 1 THEN
                    CASE
                        WHEN RS.intInterval = 1 THEN '"Days"'
                        WHEN RS.intInterval = 2 THEN '"Weeks"'
                        WHEN RS.intInterval = 3 THEN '"Months"'
                        WHEN RS.intInterval = 4 THEN '"Years"'
                    END
                Else 
                    RS.intInterval
                End
from    MyTable  AS RS WITH (NOLOCK)
```

So I want to get `intInterval`(which is `int`) if `flag` is not set to `true`. Otherwise if `flag` is set to `true`, I want to get `Days`, `Weeks`, etc depending upon value of `intInterval`. If I run this with `@bFalg = 1`, I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '"Weeks"' to data
>   type int

which does not make any sense as I am not converting anything.

I know I can fix it by putting `cast (intInterval as varchar)` in `else` part. However I want to know the reason why I am getting this error, why `case` is trying to convert 'Weeks' to `int`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using `CASE` statement, all result expressions must have the same data type. If not, the result will be converted to the data type with a higher precedence. According to [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

> Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression.

Since `INT` has a higher [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) than `VARCHAR`, `"Weeks"` get converted to `INT` and that produces the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '"Weeks"' to data
>   type int

Another example that will produce the same error:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 0 END
```

---

The solution is to convert `RS.intInterval` to `VARCHAR`:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RS.intInterval)
```

Your final query should be:

```
DECLARE @bFlag bit
SET @bFlag = 0
SELECT  something = CASE
                WHEN @bFlag = 1 THEN
                    CASE
                        WHEN RS.intInterval = 1 THEN '"Days"'
                        WHEN RS.intInterval = 2 THEN '"Weeks"'
                        WHEN RS.intInterval = 3 THEN '"Months"'
                        WHEN RS.intInterval = 4 THEN '"Years"'
                    END
                Else 
                    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RS.intInterval)
                End
from    MyTable  AS RS WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: Thanks I was looking for this bit "Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression."

Comment: This is especially annoying to track down because the error flags the branch of the case statement where there *isn't* conversion happening - it's not obvious that the problem is the *other* branch of the `CASE`.